# Is there a way to programmatically limit name resolution to entries present in /etc/hosts?

Tags: c, windows, unix, dns, getaddrinfo

Usually, I could ask `getaddrinfo` for the address of `google.com` and it will do some DNS queries and finally return me the results.

But now I have a scenario where I want to avoid the DNS lookup but limit the functionality to reading `/etc/hosts` (or `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows) and return an error if the requested entry wasn't found there.

Is there a way to force `getaddrinfo` (or any other function) to local operation? Or do I have to parse `/etc/hosts` by myself?

Answer (score 0):

For unix, that is configurable in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` (see [hosts file seems to be ignored](https://serverfault.com/questions/121890/hosts-file-seems-to-be-ignored) for discussion).

I don't recall a comparable capability with Windows, though.